# PHP 7.1 - An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference

Tags: php, php-7

I have following method, and when there is an object in the array, I will get this error:

**An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference**

```
public static function sanitizeArray(?array $array, $collation = 'UTF-8')
        {
            if(!is_array($array))
                return $array;

            array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value) use ($collation){

                if(is_object($value)){
                    foreach ($value as &$item) {
                        $item = self::sanitizeString($item, $collation);
                    }
                }else{
                    $value = self::sanitizeString($value, $collation);
                }

            });

            return $array;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you want rewrite item use `foreach ($value as $key => $item)` and then `$value[$key] = ...`

Comment: works :). Thank you :)

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko set this as an answer `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want rewrite item in array or object use `$value[$key] =` construction instead of access by reference.
So your loop code will look like:

```
foreach ($value as $key => $item) {
    $value[$key] = self::sanitizeString($item, $collation);
}
```